# How can i make a textbox wait until 2 figures are input

Tags: textbox, vb6

I need to compare the input with specific figures eg "15" or "30" or "45". But since these consist of two figures, as soon as a figure is typed in, it is compared to the above resulting in a 'wrong answer'. I need the textbox to wait for the second character ... a sort of `.minlength`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
If Len(Textbox1) = 2 And ISNUMERIC(Textbox1) Then
`~~> enter comparison here
Else
    Msgbox "Invalid input" & vbNewline & "Enter 2-digit number only"
End if
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actully, since you need it to wait until 2 chars are typed in, L42's answer won't work correctly.  Try this modification.

```
If Len(Textbox1.text) = 2 then
  if ISNUMERIC(Textbox1.text) Then
    `~~> enter comparison here
  Else
    Msgbox "Invalid input" & vbNewline & "Enter 2-digit number only"
  End if
End if
```